# Write OwinResponse content and set StatusCode at the same time

Tags: web-services, owin

Is it possible to use OwinResponse.Write while setting the status code to something other than 200?

I have the following code in an OwinMiddleware but as long as OwinResponse.Write is called the StatusCode is always set to 200 :(

```
                response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
                {
                    var resp = (OwinResponse) state;
                    var message = string.Format(
                        "Max API concurrent calls quota exceeded, please try again later. Maximum admitted: {0}",
                        _maxConcurrentRequests);
                    resp.ReasonPhrase = message;
                    resp.Write(message);
                    resp.StatusCode = 429; // doesn't work here unless I comment out the line above
                }, response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. StatusCode must be set before writing to the body, not after.
2. Don't write to the body inside OnSendingHeaders, it's recursive as
   OnSendingHeaders is usually triggered by a write to the body.
3. Why are you even using OnSendingHeaders here? Why not just do all of
   this directly on the response?
4. That's far more information than is usually included in a reason phrase. That level of detail belongs in the response body. The default reason phrase for 429 is `Too Many Requests`.

Comment: hanks.. I was following the pattern used in WebApiThrottle :)  https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle/blob/master/WebApiThrottle/ThrottlingMiddleware.cs  I will try writing on the response directly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think they needed OnSendingHeaders either. Theirs at least works because they don't write to the body.